# C# Como passar service e model para uma janela de procura

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Olá,

Tenho a seguinte situação. Um form CRUD que chama um outro form (comum ou genérico) para procura de registros...

```
private void barButtonItemProcurar_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        FrmProcura<IMarcaService> frmProcura = new FrmProcura<IMarcaService>(_marcaService);
        frmProcura.ShowDialog();
    }



public partial class FrmProcura<T> : Form
{
    private T _service;

    public FrmProcura(T service)
    {
        _service = service;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void simpleButtonFechar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void simpleButtonProcurar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //AQUI
        var dados = _service.Procura("nome", textEditConteudo.Text);

        gridControlDados.DataSource = dados;
        gridControlDados.RefreshDataSource();
    }
}
```

Mas dessa forma os métodos (exemplo do "procura") do service não são herdados (//AQUI).

Qual a melhor forma de resolver essa questão? Gostaria também de passar um model qualquer (vazio) à janela de procura para que ele volte populado com o registro escolhido na procura.

Comment: Não consegui entender muito bem o seu problema... algum erro, onde, só não funciona?

Comment: Só não funciona. Os métodos do service não são expostos. :-(

Comment: O que você quer dizer com não são expostos?

Comment: Meus services (marcas, produtos, clientes etc) tem vários metodos (procura, incluir, alterar, exclui, paginação etc). Da forma que está, eu não consigo usá-los.          ['T' does not contain a definition for 'Procura' and no accessible extension method 'Procura' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found]

Comment: Coloque por favor o código da sua interface IMarcaService e seus parents se ouver. Acho que você pode resolver implementando a definição do método procura em uma interface parent.

Answer (score 0):

Você optou por usar o `generics` em `c#`, mas não deu maiores informações ao compilador do que você "deseja" ou espera com este `tipo`... Dessa forma o compilador interpreta seu `tipo`, apenas como sendo um simples `object`, sendo assim, lhe será mostrado apenas os métodos que cabem ao tipo `object`.

Você pode utilizar a diretiva `where` para dar mais informações sobre a restrição do `tipo` que deseja receber. [Aqui você pode encontrar mais informações](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint).

No seu caso, acredito que seu código poderia ser escrito da seguinte forma:

```
public class FrmProcura<T> : Form where T : IMarcaService
{
     private T _service;
}
```

Especificando que você "espera" um `tipo` que implemente a sua interface `IMarcaService`, faz com o que o compilar entendA que seu `service` implementa `IMarcaService` e então deixará exposto todos os seus métodos e propriedades...